# SIGSEGV in vprintf() after printing result of strtok

Tags: c, printf, strtok

I'm writing some pretty basic code and I've run into an error that I'm unsure of why it is happening.

My code looks like this:

```
char* path = getenv("PATH");
if(path != NULL) {
    char* temp;
    temp = strtok(path, ":");
    printf("%s\n",path);
    printf("%s\n",temp);
}
```

The result of running this snippet causes the result:

```
/usr/local/sbin
Segmentation fault
```

If I run the program in `gdb`, I get the error

> Program recieved signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>
> 0x00007ffff7a98cba in vfprintf () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Any tips as to what is causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `getenv` documentation:

> The pointer returned by `getenv()` points to an internal memory block. The string pointed by the pointer returned by this function shall not be modified by the program. Some systems and library implementations may allow to change environmental variables with specific functions (putenv, setenv...), but such functionality is non-portable.

In other words, do not call `strtok()` over result returned by `getenv()` - create your own copy first.

Comment: If I print the path after getenv, I get "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin" so it's not that.

Comment: Just saw it. Copying the string seemed to fix my problem. Thanks!